# parameterizing linux_capabilities in ecs task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, terraform, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I have a terraform configuration to create task definition in ECS Fargate.

The **main.tf** file looks like this:

```
...

data "template_file" "td_template" {
  template = td.tpl")
  vars = {   
    linux_capabilities = ""
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "fargate" {
  family                   = "mytd"
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.td_template.rendered
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = "1024"
  memory                   = "2048"
  execution_role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/ecs"
  task_role_arn            = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/ecs"
}

...
```

And, the **td.tpl** file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "image": "xxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myserv:latest",
    "name": "myserv",
    "linuxParameters": {
      "capabilities": {
        "add": ["${linux_capabilities}"]
        }
      },
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 2048
  }
]
```

I wanted to parameterize that **linux capabilities** thing. If I add some values(for eg: below snippet) to that **linux_capabilities parameter** in data statement, It works.

```
linux_capabilities = "SYS_PTRACE"
```

But, with empty **""** doesn't work. It shows this error:

```
Error: error creating ECS Task Definition (missing-back-svc): ClientException: Unrecognized Linux capabilities in add: []
```

Does anyone has any idea about **parameterizing(set and unset)** those linux capabilities settings?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: So when you define the capability it works? But you don't want to use it? Maybe set the value to null instead of an empty string and check if that works.

Comment: You can see the example here that I have on how to pass list and map to tpl file: https://github.com/tomarv2/terraform-aws-ecs/blob/main/modules/ecs/container-definition.tf

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the double quotes in the template. You have no way of creating the JSON `"add": []` the best you can do is `"add": [""]` which is invalid. Passing `null` would give you `"add": ["null"]`

Also, you are using the deprecated `template_file` resource, instead of the newer built-in [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) function.

I suggest switching to `templatefile`, and then adding a [conditional directive](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#string-templates) in your template that completely removes the `"capabilities": {}` block if there is an empty string or `null` passed in.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B. I will try that. But, we have having our doubts with terraform deployment and planning to create a custom boto3 script for that.

I will check the above one and Let you know.